# Java Print the perfect squares less than an input using a while loop

Tags: java

This is a homework assignment that I am stuck on that maybe someone could help me with:

"Write a program using a while loop that prints the perfect squares less than an input 'n'. For instance, if n=30, print 25, 16, 9, 4, 2, 1, 0,"

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fourpointone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int input, output;

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner num= new Scanner(System.in);
        input = num.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        while(input>=0){

            System.out.println(Math.pow(input, 2));
            --input;

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("are the perfect squares less than your input");
    }

}
```

It gives me all the perfect squares below my input squared. Like I get the squares 49 on down if I enter 7. I thought maybe there's a way for it to only print the result below the value of the input but I don't know how to do that. There's probably a more simple way to do the whole thing but I haven't figured it out so far.

Comment: Hint: does it matter in which order the squares are printed?

Comment: i don't think so but I assume it should be top to bottom or bottom to top

Comment: Look at Math.sqrt and Math.floor

Comment: Hint: You may consider using `Math.floor` and `Math.pow(input, 0.5)`

Comment: @Daveythewavey19 I'll try phrase it in a way that should make it a bit clearer: `square all the numbers (starting at 0, increasing by 1) until the resulting square is above the input value`. Naturally this is homework so we'd be doing you a disservice by just handing you the code.

Comment: @Daveythewavey19 left you a hint as an answer - try think through what you're trying to do logically.

Comment: There's a (good) way to do this without any multiplications at all :) (Hint: every successive pair of triangle numbers sums to a perfect square)

Comment: As suggested by @GregS you could use Math.floor(Math.sqrt(input)) and lets say the value is n.  Now loop through 0..n and print the squares using Math.pow()

Answer (score 0):

You're making it more complicated by going in reverse (it's surprising how often this is the case). The simplest way is to start incrementing a loop at 0, and increment by 1 inside the loop each time.

Since this is homework, I shall leave it to you to figure out how you exit your loop - but it's quite simple if you start incrementing from 0, rather than decrementing from the highest value you want. Although leave a comment if you're still having trouble.

Alternatively, if it's required to be in highest to lowest; you can make use of `Math.sqrt` to check if the root is a whole number (hint hint).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int A = sc.nextInt();
int i =1;
while((i*i)<=A) {         
  System.out.print(i*i +" ");
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)